# Человек, следящий за новостями в мире

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Добрый день!

Как можно назвать одним словом человека, следящего( возможно, даже параноидально  ) за новостями в мире?

Comment: Что, и такая мания существует? Не встречала.Вот каиномания - ненормальный интерес к новинкам
Паратерезиомания - нездоровый интерес к созерцанию всё новых видов и достопримечательностей. А вот это - просто архилюбитель новостей, архи любознательный, пусть параноидально любознательный. Можно сказать"он параноик новостей", просто "параноик"

Comment: @Людмила, спасибо вам большое за ваши ценные рассуждения! Вот только слово "параноик" никак тут не подойдет - ведь паранойя может касаться стольких вещей повседневности, что их не перечесть..а мне бы хотелось отыскать точное слово, характеризующее человека, хотя бы просто увлекающегося новостями.

Comment: Новолюб  -  это  просто  любитель  новенького.  В  разных  сферах,  как  книголюб,  женолюб  и  другие  "любы".

Answer (score 3):

**Ньюсвизор**, по аналогии с ньюсмейкер вам не подойдёт? Оказионализм, конечно, но на безрыбье и рак - рыба.

Comment: Ньюсвизор - классно придумано, но есть ли такое слово в русском языке( как, собственно, и "ньюсмейкер" )?

Comment: @Asen, ньюсмейкер скорее есть чем нет, а ньюсвизор не уверен, что и в английском существует. Однако какой-нибудь *новостелюб* или *нунциман* (от лат. nuntius — вестник) будет лучше.

Comment: Хм, в таком случае, думаю, нужно что-то "более русское", чем "ньюсвизор".

Answer (score 3):

Чтоб и русское, и в словаре было... Такого, наверное, нет. Но мне еще вот какое образование пришло на ум.  Есть алкоголик. Потом появились разговорные "трудоголик". Позже "шопоголик", "пищеголик". Почему бы не быть слову "ньюголик"("ньюсоголик") или "новостеголик"? Разве только потому, что таких людей мало? Чтобы именно новости отслеживал? Чаще, действительно, это тот, кто у телевизора просиживает-пролеживает и смотрит все подряд.

Answer (score 2):

Термин может зависеть от мотивации и цели слежения. Варианты: обозреватель, эксперт — это если по служебному долгу. Ньюсман, ньюсоман по аналогии с меломаном, наркоманом и проч. — если это одинокий пенсионер как придаток к телевизору.

Comment: Хм, Спасибо вам. Ну вот только "обозреватель" все же, думаю, слишком многозначное слово, т.е тут вряд ли лишь по одному этому слову можно будет понять, что человек увлекается новостями, касающимися обстановки в мире. А вот "Ньюсман" - это же, скорее, как "журналист". Собственно, с английского примерно так и переводится. Да и есть ли в русском языке такое слово вообще?

Comment: В советские времена была телепрограмма "Обозреватели за круглым столом". Человека три сообщали, трактовали и толковали самые главные мировые политико-экономические новости за неделю. Надо полагать, что у них самих, а особо у группы их помощников, это служебная обязанность была одной из основных. Это шоу *без расстояний* теперь прижилось на многих телеканалах.

А был такой — Андрей Анатольевич Егоршев (родился 26 сентября 1965 года, Жуковский) — российский теле- и радиоведущий, основатель жанра «обзор прессы». Увы, не прижилось...

Comment: Да, я даже, признаться, как-то слышал об этой телевизионной передаче, но тут уже, скорее, все советские люди просто знали, что в данном контексте обозначало слово "обозреватель"( то ли оттого, что смотреть было нечего, то ли все советские люди были заядлыми любителями новостей ), а вот в современное время есть и "обозреватели игр"(видео, устройств и много чего еще), так что нынче одним лишь этим слово не отделаться)

Comment: Поскольку  в  вопросе  есть  намёк  на  манию,  думаю,  что  лучший  вариант  -  ньюсман  или  новостеман.

Answer (score 2):

Ньюсхаунтер? от news и haunter (навязчивая идея). Не совсем, конечно, русское слово получилось))) Но по-русски в одно слово, наверно, и не скажешь.. А Вам одним словом требуется?

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, впервые слышу о такой мании. Но вот, например, журналист, который занимается новостями, называется новостейщик. Может, и тут так?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте назовем его "новолюбом", первую основу пришлось подрезать для благозвучности. Это будет настоящий любитель, а не профессиональный журналист на новостях.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю,  новостеман  лучше  отвечает  характеру  вопроса.

Comment: Смысловое значение у слова, действительно, точное, но оно неудобно с точки зрения фонетики. Пусть будет тогда "новоман".

Comment: Как  говорил  Остап  Бендер - торг  здесь  неуместен.

Answer (score 0):

Было интересно познакомиться с предлагаемыми вариантами для обозначения понятия "человек, следящий за новостями в мире". Однако все они являются окказионализмами.

Comment: Естесственно.

Answer (score 0):

Во времена ФИДО такая мания была замечена сообществом и даже выражена поговоркой "Семеро первонахов теребят F5" (семеро любителей сообщать самые свежие новости находятся в повышенной готовности к их отправке). Но потом стремление первым сообщить новость было признано нездоровым (страдали и полнота, и достоверность) и слово "первонах" приобрело отрицательную окраску (чему способствовало его некошерное происхождение). И кануло в бездну.

Comment: У  меня  вопросик:  что  такое  ФИДО ?

Comment: ФИДО (фидонет) - любительская некоммерческая информационная сеть, существовавшая на альтруистических началах в доинтернетовские времена. Люди обменивались в ней в основном текстовыми письмами, причём очень неспешно - почта шла сутками, а то и неделями и передавалась телефонными модемами с килобитовыми скоростями. Но потом средства связи улучшились, появились возможности покупки нормальных каналов и ФИДОшники разбрелись по интернету... Впрочем, некоторые традиции местами сохранились дольше - например, в чатах файлообменника DC++

Answer (score 0):

"вирусньюс"? Думаю, вполне "злободневное" слово

Comment: Подхвативший  вирус  новостемании ?